# R - Построение диаграммы

Tags: r, ggplot2

Проведен опрос ,по его данным нужно построить разные диаграммы, но почему то при построении возникает лишний столбец со значением NA, хотя чистила данные по конкретному вопросу с помощью complete.cases.
Вот скрипт:

```
table(df_google$При.переходе.на.удаленную.работу.контроль.со.стороны.руководителя.уменьшился.)
df_google$control=factor(df_google$При.переходе.на.удаленную.работу.контроль.со.стороны.руководителя.уменьшился.,levels = c ('Да','Скорее да, чем нет','Скорее нет, чем да','Нет'))

df_google$control <-  df_google[complete.cases(df_google$control), ]

g <- ggplot(df_google, aes(df_google$control,fill=df_google$work),args.legend = list(x = "top"))

g+geom_bar(position = "fill")+
xlab("Уменьшился контроль со стороны руководства")+
  ylab("Количество респондентов")+
  scale_fill_discrete(name="Как на Ваш взгляд изменилась 
  Ваша производительность")+
  ggtitle("График зависимости производительности труда от контроля руководства")
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Нужно убрать последний столбец на графике(NA). С droplevels тоже пробовала чистить данные по этому вопросу.

Comment: Заголовок должен описать проблему в нескольких словах. И в книгах (если это не дичь какая-то) это делается.

Answer (score 2):

`df_google$control <-  df_google[complete.cases(df_google$control), ]` следует заменить на `df_google <-  df_google[complete.cases(df_google$control), ]`, чтобы вы переписали датасет. А то сейчас во второй части (справа от присваивания) меньше элементов, слева от присваивания больше, но во всем датасете тоже больше. Так что он оставляет как во всем датасете.

Comment: Спасибо большое! получилось